# Merging only the sublists but not all of them into one list in Python

Tags: python, list

Could somebody please tell me how can I merge the following list:

`[[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a'], ['c', 'c']], [['d', 'e'], ['e', 'd']]]`

into:

`[['ab', 'ba', 'cc'], ['de', 'ed']]`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to map the join on all the sublists:

```
l = [[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a'], ['c', 'c']], [['d', 'e'], ['e', 'd']]]

out = [list(map(''.join, x)) for x in l]
```

Or:

```
out = [[''.join(i) for i in x] for x in l
```

Output: `[['ab', 'ba', 'cc'], ['de', 'ed']]`

Answer (score 0):

Two methods:

1. Use `map()` and `''.join`:

```py
data = [[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a'], ['c', 'c']], [['d', 'e'], ['e', 'd']]]
result = [list(map(''.join, item)) for item in data]
print(result)
```

2. Use a list comprehension:

```py
data = [[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a'], ['c', 'c']], [['d', 'e'], ['e', 'd']]]
result = [[''.join(item) for item in sublist] for sublist in data]
print(result)
```

Both of these print:

```py
[['ab', 'ba', 'cc'], ['de', 'ed']]
```